# Change URL every 10min based on redirect

Tags: php, redirect, random

I got 10 urls in a file.

I want to show each url for 10 minutes and when done start over again.

```
<?php

$version = "v1.01";

$linksfile = "urlrotator.txt";

$urls = file("$linksfile");
$url = rand(0, sizeof($urls) - 1);

$goto = "$urls[$url]";

header("Location: $goto");
```

This just rotate random.

Need to be based on time

The `urlrotator.txt` content look like following

```
nr1.html
nr2.html
nr3.html
nr4.html
nr5.html
nr6.html
nr7.html
nr8.html
nr9.html
nr10.html
```

Comment: <?php

$version = "v1.01";

$linksfile ="urlrotator.txt";

$urls = file("$linksfile");
$url = rand(0, sizeof($urls)-1);

$goto = "$urls[$url]";

header("Location: $goto");

?>

code I got

Comment: What you have tried so far? Share the code

Comment: Update your question with code, remove code from comment

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `time` function to find the current second, and from that the current 10-minute chunk.  Then use a modulo to find the remainder according to the number of URLs you have.

```
$minutesBetweenChanges = 10;

$urls = file('urlrotator.txt');
$numberOfURLs = count($urls);

$selection = (int) ((time() / 60) / $minutesBetweenChanges) % $numberOfURLs;

header('Location: ' . $urls[$selection]);
```